# Getting a list of EntityValidationErrors' in the immediate window

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

How can I get a list of errors in the immediate window when this breaks in VS 2012

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

there doesn't appear to be a simple way of displaying them without creating some code modifications to loop through them like so:

```
foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
       string validationErrors="";

        foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
        {
           validationErrors+=error.PropertyName+"  "+error.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception)
```

in the Watch window will give you access to the exception instance. You can check out the error collection from there.

I keep that available in my Watch list so I can just refresh if I run into that exception.

Comment: EF has been a great source of pain, esp when trying to serialise it into json, today I had to scrap my db and re migrate it