# DbEntityValidationException unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, database, validation, savechanges

I am making an MVC .Net application and I have have trouble understanding why my db.SaveChanges(); is not working and creating an validation error.  I have been looking through stack but I am having trouble finding a solid explanation of this problem.

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include"Id, EventTitle, EventSubTitle, EventAddress,EventCity,EventState,EventZip,EventCreator,EventTime,EventDiscription")] Event @event, AspNetUser @user)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
@event.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
@event.EventCreator = @user.Id;
db.Events.Add(@event);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

My thought is that the user.Id needs to be connected to the Event model to validate but I thought I would ask.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Try looping through the validation errors (in a try catch) or something like the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303730/getting-a-list-of-entityvalidationerrors-in-the-immediate-window). I am guessing one or more of those properties can't be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbEntityValidationException to my experience is thrown when there are problems similar to the followings:

- The size of data inside one or more entities is greater than the one accepted inside the database. For example, if in your database you have a table Person with Name Varchar(20) and in the entity you are trying to save you have a name longer than 20, the exception will be thrown
- You are trying to add an entity with a primary key which already exists
- Violation of a foreign key or other things which relate to your database

How to avoid this exception?
Validate your data before to save it in the database.
It seems that you are doing it with ModelState.IsValid, but we don't see the code for the validation process.
Check that validation is correct, inline with the rules of your database.

Note: in a professional application, usually you don't call DbContext directly from your controller.

Comment: I found a great way around this by using the Watch Window.  Simply open the debug tab and select windows, watch.  then just past this into the Name felid.    ((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors         you can then find a list of what is not moving to the database.   Thanks for your help!